# Converting hex strings to decimal strings in Visual Basic for Applications (Excel)

Tags: vba, hex, decimal

I am trying to convert a hex string to a decimal string, to input into an Excel spreadsheet, but I am having no luck finding any solutions to the problem. I can successfully display the hex string in Excel, but I want to convert it to a decimal string before pushing it to the Excel spreadsheet.

I have tried the following (also see code currently commented out):

```
Private Function ToHexString(ByRef buffer As Variant) As String
    ReDim bytes(LBound(buffer) + 6 To LBound(buffer) + 9)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(buffer) + 6 To LBound(buffer) + 9
        bytes(i) = Hex(buffer(i))
    Next
    ToHexString = Strings.Join(bytes, "")
End Function

Function FromHex(hexString As String) As Long
    FromHex = Val("&H" & hexString)
End Function

Private Sub StrokeReader1_CommEvent(ByVal Evt As StrokeReaderLib.Event, ByVal data As Variant)
  Select Case Evt
    Case EVT_DISCONNECT
        Debug.Print "Disconnected"

    Case EVT_CONNECT
        Debug.Print "Connected"

    Case EVT_DATA
        buf = StrokeReader1.Read(BINARY) 'Use BINARY to receive a byte array
        Debug.Print ToHexString(buf)
       ' Debug.Print buf
      '  Debug.Print "myStr length: " & Len(buf)
           'using `StrConv` to allow for 2-byte unicode character storage

       ' dist = Convert.ToInt32("c001", 16)



       ' ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ToHexString(buf)
    ' int number = Convert.ToInt32(buf, 16);

        'buf = "0081C"

       ' Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("c001", 16)

       'hexDist = ToHexString(buf)
       'distInt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hexDist, 16)

        'decLong = FromHex(buf)

        Dim hexVal As String
        hexVal = ToHexString(buf)
        Dim intVal As Integer
        intVal = Convert.ToInt32(hexVal, 16)

        ActiveCell.Value = intVal
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select




  End Select
End Sub
```

The hex string typically looks like this: 00A57
and the decimal string output should look like this: 2647

I am getting Syntax errors or Error 402, depending on what I try to make work.

Comment: this hex string is stored in hexVal, right?

Comment: Your function `ToHexString` encodes some bytes on a single character when it should be on 2: `Right(Hex(256 + buffer(i)), 2)`. Note that you could read the number directly with `myint32 = buffer(0) + buffer(1)*256 + buffer(1)*1024 + ...` or with `RtlMoveMemory(myint32, buffer(0), 4)`or by loading the bytes in a [User Defined Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the corresponding part of your code to:

```vb
Dim intVal as Long
intVal = FromHex(hexVal)
```